# The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I got this error after I have inserted `data` from `excel` file to `sql server`. According to the data on excel the table created by the `SSMS` automatically and ended up with 7 rows of `null` values for all fields.

Error was,

> The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique
>   or they alter multiple rows(7 rows)

This is interesting because when I search in `stackoverflow` I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859306/the-row-values-updated-or-deleted-either-do-not-make-the-row-unique-or-they-alte) and it doesn't help me since I have only `null` values on my table for 7 rows that I want to delete.

I use below `T-sql` but it affects no rows,

```
Delete top(1) from [tableName] where [columnName]= NULL

Delete top(1) from [tableName] where [columnName]= 'NULL'
```

Help to delete that 7 rows are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that SQL Server wants you to use an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM [tableName]
    WHERE [columnName] IS NULL
    ORDER BY some_col
)

DELETE FROM cte;
```

Note that `NULL` checks have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  Equality checks against `NULL` are not well defined.

Comment: Great. `IS NULL` is working like charm. But `Order by` gives a syntax error. But this resolved my problem.

Comment: @SilentCoder Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` does not make much sense.  Check my updated answer.